# Android Studio: fit ImageView to different screensizes

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-imageview, android-drawable

[image]

Hi, having bit of a trouble fitting the different src(images) to fit nicely to all the different screen sizes.

Do i have to add different imageSolutions of the image in the drawable map? Any smart solutions?

Comment: In short, yes.  You should add different resolutions for as many screen sizes as you can.  Because if you use just one, it will look great on one device, and tiny on a larger one.  And screen size isn't the only thing.  There is also pixel density.

Answer (score 0):

Android images require five separate sizes for different screen pixel densities. Icons for lower resolution are created automatically from the baseline.

- mdpi (Baseline): 160 dpi -   1×
- hdpi:                240 dpi  -   1.5×
- xhdpi:               320 dpi  -   2×
- xxhdpi:              490 dpi -   3×
- xxxhdpi:         640 dpi  -   4×

here http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/ is more information

The X means the size of your baseline image

Try using layouts to center the image, play with weigth of layouts